# Swapping two successive elements in a list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I have a list of elements and I would like to create a Haskell function of this type :

`swap :: [Token] -> [Token]`

Given this data : `data Token = Number | Operator`

In the function I would like to check if two successive elements (starting from the beggining) are "swappable". Two elements are swappable if the first one is `Number` and the following one is `Operator`.

I have started to design a function like this but not sure how to complete it :

```
swap :: [Token] -> [Token]
swap [] = []
swap (x:xs) = if ( x == Number ) and ( xs!!0 == Operator ) then
                -- swap here
              else 
                swap (xs)
```

I don't know how to do the swap though.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Do you know how to write `map` and `filter` yourself?

Answer (score 2):

You just need to construct a list with elements swapped and return it:

```
data Token = Number | Operator deriving (Eq, Show)

swap :: [Token] -> [Token]
swap (x:y:xs) = if x == Number && y == Operator then
                  y : x : swap xs
                else 
                  x : swap (y : xs)
swap xs = xs


main = putStrLn $ show $ swap [Number, Number, Number, Operator, Operator, Number, Operator, Number]
-- Output: [Number,Number,Operator,Number,Operator,Operator,Number,Number]
```

[Run it](http://ideone.com/m8z8sR)

Alternatively, you can use pattern matching instead of `if/else`:

```
swap :: [Token] -> [Token]
swap (x@Number:y@Operator:xs) = y : x : swap xs
swap (x:xs) = x : swap xs
swap [] = []
```

[Run it](http://ideone.com/HXa353)

Comment: I've got the following error : 
ERROR "save.hs":5 - Type error in application
*** Expression     : (x == Operator) and (y == Number)
*** Term           : (==)
*** Type           : a -> a -> Bool
*** Does not match : b -> c -> d -> e -> f

Comment: I think your code isn't correct, it isn't defined on singleton.

Comment: @PierreP. the infix and operator is spelled `&&`, not `and` (that's something different)

Comment: @PierreP  I edited the answer - this time I've actually checked if the code compiles ;)

Comment: Now, you can remove equation `swap [] = []`  and I believe that with pattern matching you can simplify your code :)

Comment: @freestyle right - because `swap xs = xs` case handles empty list - good catch! :)